# Exception Error when Installing NumPy with pip

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

I have been trying to install NumPy and have been have a brutal time with it. I keep getting an exception error no matter what I try. I used the command

```
$pip install numpy
```

but it threw this error

```
    Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 693, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 817, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1018, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 269, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in clobber
      shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
      with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
  IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/man/man1/nosetests.1'
```

Just to check, I used import in Python to see if it got anything, it also threw an error though. I have no idea what is going on.

```
$pip install scipy
```

gave me no problems. Any help is appreciated! I can't seem to find anything on how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it tries to install globally, so you need permissions for that, or use virtualenv to create virtual storage where you can install numpy without problem.

Exactly in your case it says it cannot copy file to `/usr/local/man/man1/nosetests.1`

Comment: Okay. How would I get the permissions for it? Would sudo do the right thing? I should also mention, when I tried running pip again, it told me that numpy was already installed and up to date.

Comment: Yes, `sudo` may help you. Or, if you don't need it globally, try to create a `virtualenv`

Comment: Trying to run it with sudo tells me the same as the when I ran it the second time, that it is already installed and up to date. I do need it globally.

Comment: Try `pip uninstall numpy` and `sudo install numpy` after them.

Comment: @wanderlust: That's a bad idea. The more stuff you `sudo` into `/usr/local`, the more problems you'll have with Homebrew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) tries to leave /usr/local writable, so you don't need `sudo`. [See the FAQ for details.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-)

However, if you accidentally use `sudo` once—or if some other installer you run installs stuff into `/usr/local` that doesn't realize you wanted it Homebrew-style—then you'll start getting errors, when your Homebrew stuff attempt to modify files that were saved with `sudo`.

There's a particular problem if you try to use both Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7 and a Homebrew Python 2.7: they both want to install scripts to `/usr/local/bin`, man pages to `/usr/local/man`, etc. And Apple's wants to use sudo.

So, most likely, you did a `sudo pip install nose` for Apple's Python in the past, and now `pip install nose` for Homebrew's Python is trying to overwrite its files and doesn't have permissions to do so. (Or maybe not `nose` itself, but something else that requires `nose` without you realizing it.)

Using `sudo` with the Homebrew Python will just make the problem worse; don't do that.

The right solution is to either:

- Not use a third-party Python 2.7, Homebrew or otherwise, and just stick with Apple's (or upgrade to Python 3; then there's usually no conflict with Apple's 2.7…), or
- Never touch Apple's Python 2.7, and only use the other one.

But at this point, you've already screwed things up, and I doubt you want to reinstall your OS from scratch, right?

You can fix things by `brew uninstall python` for the former, or by uninstalling everything you installed with Apple's Python for the latter. (You can't uninstall Apple's Python; that would break the OS, and the next OS update would just undo it anyway…) And then, either way, you'll probably want to reinstall every package you need for whichever Python you chose to go with, to be safe.

Or, for a quick&dirty solution, every time you get an error like this, you can either delete the conflicting file (`sudo rm /usr/local/man/man1/nosetests.1`) or make it overwritable (`sudo chmod a+w /usr/local/man/man1/nosetests.1`); then, your `pip` will work. Until the next error, which you can fix the same way.

Comment: Okay. Is there an easy way to clean all my added stuff up and go to scratch without a rebuild? Most stuff I need is fairly organized, so a rebuild wouldn't be the end of the world. I am guessing that just from trying to load different packages from different sources I have created problems all over the place. What's the easiest way to get back to scratch? Thanks!

Comment: @Grimey: Which way do you want to end up? Apple site-packages and no Homebrew, or Homebrew site-packages and empty Apple site-packages? The first one is simpler, but if it's not the one you want, that doesn't help… Also, have you ever installed any packages without `pip` (or do you not know the answer to that)?

Comment: I have certainly tried to install packages. I am still quite new to Python, so I have tried installing packages in a plethora of different ways. In retrospect, should have read more into it. It seems to me that homebrew is useful and has many useful packages. Maybe this would be the best way to go? Which would you suggest? I am pretty indifferent.

Comment: First, for installing programs and shared libraries, Homebrew is definitely the way to go, even if you don't use it for Python itself. As for which Python to use… well, I'd say learn Python 3, then leave Apple's as the only 2.7, which you rarely use, and install 3.4 from python.org or Homebrew. If you can't do that, I personally think it's easier to stick with Apple's Python 2.7, but a lot of people disagree. (I wrote [a blog post a couple years ago explaining why](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/02/sticking-with-apples-python-27.html).)

Comment: @Grimey: Or, since you're looking to install NumPy and SciPy… have you looked into using one of the scientific distributions of Python+extras, like Enthought or PythonXY? (Maybe not those two in particular–I think the first is non-free and the second doesn't yet work on Mac—but there are others.) That would get you not just NumPy and SciPy, but also Qt (which is much more painful to set up) and other things, and some of them have self-contained package management…

Comment: Okay. I like the idea of installing Python 3, only problem is that I am working on a project with some other people and they are running Python 2.7. Maybe it would be a good idea to keep Homebrew for my personal use, then load up NumPy, SciPy, Biopython, and bx-python onto Apple python. I think this would be the best way to go. So, how would I go about cleaning up to get back to Mac's "default python state"? I'm sure it's hard to totally clean up. Thanks!

Comment: @Grimey: Yeah, if you're working on a project with other people on 2.7, the project will be 2.7, so you have to use 2.7. But if you're planning to use Apple's Python for that project, but a Homebrew 3.4 for your own personal use, cleaning up should be easy: just `brew uninstall python`, then make sure you have `pip` installed for Apple's Python and `sudo pip2.7 install` everything you need, then `brew install python3` for your personal 3.4.

Comment: @Grimey: Depending on your OS X version, Apple may have preinstalled NumPy for you. Also, you may need to `brew install gcc` if you want Fortran-optimized SciPy. Also, do you know about [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)? (3.4 has an equivalent built in as `venv`, but 2.7 doesn't.) If you're trying to maintain multiple Python environments, `virtualenv` is a lot easier than remembering when to use `sudo` and which commands need `2.7` vs. `2` suffixes and worrying about screwing up your central site-packages.

Comment: I have heard of virtualenv, although I don't kow much about it. I would love to learn more. The other thing I am a little worried about is that I believe at one point I installed via python.org, and I have installed from all sorts of different .tar.gz files. Is there any easy way to make sure I get all of it cleaned up as far as deleting some of the other packages installed?

Comment: @Grimey: I'm pretty sure the python.org build isn't a problem, as it sets any packages to install everything into `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.Y` (and then tells you to add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/X.Y/bin` to your `PATH`), so just removing `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` cleans up everything.

Comment: @Grimey: But Homebrew and Apple Python, while they handle site-packages itself nicely, I think they both put scripts, manpages, etc. in `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/man`, etc., so you may have to clean those out. And I don't know any way to automate that. Some of them may be symlinks, so just `ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep /usr/local/Cellar/python` or similar will make them easy to find. For others, you can `pip list` and then try to guess which files sound like they go with which packages, then look at those files and verify you're right.

Comment: @Grimey: Also, any script that was automatically generated by `setuptools`, which should be most of them, will be easy to verify; it'll have a `#!` pointing to one particular Python, then a comment with the pip info for the package, then 5 lines of boilerplate code where the only interesting bit is `load_entry_point('spam=1.2', 'console_scripts', 'spam')`.

Answer (score -3):

Just run cmd as Admin it worked for me.